# Почему mercurial притягивает коммиты из других веток?

Tags: mercurial

Есть две ветки - master (прод) и default (тестовая среда). Каждая новая задача - это новая ветка от master. После выполнения она сливается с default, тестируется, потом сливается с master.
Создаю новую ветку от master, вношу изменения в 3х файлах, коммичу, сливаю с default - притягиваются коммиты из других веток (те, которые сливались с master недавно) т.е. mercurial, чтобы смотреть в 3 закоммиченных файла, смотрит везде и вываливает кучу конфликтов...
Нормальное ли такое поведение системы контроля версий и как это можно исправить?

Comment: если эти три файла поменялись - да, похоже на обычное дело.

Comment: 1. Коммиты не "притягиваются" - это гравитация и не притяжение металлов к магнитам.
2. При слиянии двух бранчей данные берутся от ближайшего общего предка (и это описано в букваре), а не только "последние мои изменения"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Нормальное ли такое поведение системы контроля версий

Да, оно не только *нормальное*, но и *правильное*

> как это можно исправить?

Никак. Просто навести порядок в организационных процессах в организации (и в головах):

- При merge двух бранчей

  - находится последний общий предок
  - находятся (и агрегируются) все изменения, произошедшие в бранче-источнике со времени этого changeset-a
  - суммарный diff в итоге предыдущего пункта и будет тем, что должно и будет применяться к бранчу-приемнику
  - если master ведется правильно (там нет ничего, кроме `branchpoint()` + `merge()` в синтаксисе ревсетов), то никакие "коммиты из других веток" в принципе "притягиваться" не могут

Если нужен более разжеванный до кашицы ответ, то стоит показывать в вопросе больше информации, к примеру DAG проблемной части (`hg log -G ...`) с указанием, какие такие коммиты из "других ветвей" (какие? откуда?) в каком merge оказались неожиданно участвующими. Тогда будет нормальный ответ, а не гадание

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Это обычное поведение. Если вы одновременно с кем-то вносите изменения в одни и те же файлы, то процедура слияния, используемая по-умолчанию, всегда будет выдавать конфликты. Внешние merge tools могут разрешать некоторые типы конфликтов.

[image: pic1]

- A - Вы завершили задачу почти одновременно с другим SDE (коммиты 4, 5)
- B - Но потом тот успел раньше вас слить с default и master
- С - В то время как вы сливали с локальным default и разрешали конфликты

[image: pic2]

- D - Вы хотели сделать push, но оказалось, что на ветке default две головы
- E - Потребуется опять сливать и разрешать конфликты

Вариант, когда вы один сливаете изменения.

[image: pic3]

- C-2 - После выполнения задачи (коммит 5), вы подтягиваете изменения
- D-2 - Сливаете с default и master и разрешаете конфликты

В принципе, число конфликтов будет одинаковым, только в первом варианте разделено на две части - сначала вы сливаете изменения коммитов 3-5, потом 6-7. А во втором случае - сразу 3-6-5.

По умолчанию используется [merge tool](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/hg.1.html#choosing-a-merge-tool) `:merge`. Но по мне, что `:merge`, что `:merge3` работают одинаково плохо. Поэтому я использую `kdiff3` - настраивается в [.hgrc (или mercurial.ini)](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/hgrc.5.html#merge-tools). Только kdiff3, который поставляется с TortoiseHg весьма устарел, и похоже заброшен. Более свежий можно [взять](https://mirrors.dotsrc.org/kde/stable/kdiff3/) из состава KDE, только там бывают весьма нестабильные версии, надо пробовать разные.

Comment: Вопрос был не про "сложности merge" и "конфликты" в процессе.